# How to update an existing GeoJSON with Fiona

Tags: gdal, geojson, fiona

With the code below I can create a new GeoJSON and add data to it:

```
data =[(LINESTRING (-98.98234 19.38234, -98.990341 19.342345, -98.992449 19.378621, -98.991299 19.378233, -98.992349999 19.377381), 1)]
schema = {'geometry': 'LineString','properties': {'id': 'int', 'name': 'str'}}
with fiona.open(file_name,'w','GeoJSON', schema) as output:
    for id, name in data:
        output.write({'geometry':mapping(line), 'properties':{'id':id, 'name':name}})
```

How can I write to an existing GeoJSON? Is that possible with the GeoJSON driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiona doesn't support updating existing layers by design. You'll need to read your existing data in, make the changes you need, and write to a new file.

Comment: JSON is mostly a write-once format anyway. There are tricks to getting around this, but the format doesn't help at all.